# отваливается webhook в telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Имею следующую проблему: бот на php, уже написан, работает нормально. Прицеплен вебхуком. Время от времени, примерно раз в сутки, иногда чаще, иногда реже, вебхук исчезает, как будто его вообще не было. Не могу понять, с чем это связано. Каждый раз захожу на `api.telegram.org/bot*token*/setWebhook?url=https://domain/bot.php`, получаю нормальный отзыв "Webhook was set", но затем он перестает работать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Это не возможно, я пишу ботов на заказ, у меня за все время работы такого ни когда не было. Удалите вебхук и установите заново. Обязательно должен быть сертификат, если нет то его нужно в запросе  установки вебхука указать. Но если бы что то пошло не так, вы бы увидели ошибку сразу. У вас точно нет кого то или чего то что удаляет вам настройки вебхука?

Comment: ну как невозможно, происходит же :) при удалении вебхука появляется сообщение, что вебхука нет, ставлю заново. https работает. со времени написания вопроса один раз проблема решилась, бот долго работал без проблем, сейчас вебхук опять падает. рабочая версия - виноваты ошибки в коде, не глобальные, когда бот сразу же не работает, а мелкие, типа повторяющихся ключей в каком-нибудь массиве внутри бота либо функции, и ошибка происходит тогда, когда рендом попадает конкретно на этот массив/ключ/функцию, затем они накапливаются и происходит отключение. так что сижу дебажу по кусочкам.

Comment: в то-то и штука, что нигде в мануалах и апи не описаны условия, при которых вебхук может самостоятельно отстреливаться и где посмотреть причины отключения о_О приходится методом тыка. в прошлый раз починилось после устранения какого-то бага внутри бота.